# How to move elements from one LinkedList to another based on criteria

Tags: c#, .net

I have two LinkedLists, I'd like to move all elements which match some criteria from LinkedListA to LinkedListB (LinkedListB is not empty to start with). Any ideas?

Comment: Move them where?  To the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're moving from list a to the end of list b, try this method:

```
// .Net 2.0 compatable
private static void moveFromFirstToSecond<T>(Predicate<T> match, LinkedList<T> first, LinkedList<T> second)
{
    LinkedListNode<T> current = first.First;
    while (current != null)
    {
        LinkedListNode<T> next = current.Next;
        if (match(current.Value))
        {
            second.AddLast(current.Value); // second.AddLast(current) also works
            first.Remove(current);
        }
        current = next;
    }
}

// for strings that start with "W"
LinkedList<string> a = ...
LinkedList<string> b = ...
moveFromFirstToSecond(delegate(string toMatch)
    { return toMatch.StartsWith("W"); }, a, b);
```

or as an extension method:

```
// .Net 3.5 or later
public static void MoveMatches<T>(this LinkedList<T> first, Predicate<T> match, LinkedList<T> other)
{
    LinkedListNode<T> current = first.First;
    while (current != null)
    {
        LinkedListNode<T> next = current.Next;
        if (match(current.Value))
        {
            other.AddLast(current.Value); // other.AddLast(current) also works
            first.Remove(current);
        }
        current = next;
    }
}

// for strings that start with "W"
LinkedList<string> a = ...
LinkedList<string> b = ...
a.MoveMatches(x => x.StartsWith("W"), b);
```

Comment: Would this work:

private static void moveFromFirstToSecond<T>(Predicate<T> match, LinkedList<T> first, LinkedList<T> second)
{
    LinkedListNode<T> current = first.First;
    while (current != null)
    {
        LinkedListNode<T> next = current.Next;
        if (match(current.Value))
        {
            first.Remove(current);
            second.AddLast(current);
        }
        current = next;
    }
}

Comment: @cskilbeck, I'm not sure. The question is if the overloaded AddLast method of LinkedList<T> includes the Next and Previous nodes.  If it does, then you'd be copying the entire chain instead of just the value.

Comment: Just verified, changing second.AddLast(current.Value); to second.AddLast(current); behaves the same, so they both work.

Comment: I know your answer is rather old and things might have been different back then, but since I got this as one of the first results when searching for the topic...
Your comment `// other.AddLast(current) also works` is wrong, as you can not add a node that belongs to a LinkedList to another LinkedList (throws a InvalidOperationException). So, to make `AddLast(current)` work, just remove it before from the source list, not after. Actually, it would be much more efficient as it re-uses the node instead of creating a new one and discarding the old one, and there is no downside (at least AFAICS).